# Using Android Location Services in a XamarinForms App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, locationmanager, location-services

I have a Xamarin Forms Application. Fairly basic setup with a PCL containing some XAML Pages.

I'm trying to get a very simple "display my gps co-ordinates" sample running based on a button click in my Xaml Page.

I've created an ILocationService interface in my PCL, and an android specific implementation in my Android app, tagged with the `[assembly:Dependency]` attribute so I can fetch it with the XamForms DI Service.

Here's the code for the Android Implementation.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidLocationService))]

namespace LoginDemo.Droid
{
    public class AndroidLocationService : ILocationService, ILocationListener
    {
        Location _currentLocation;
        LocationManager _locationManager;
        String _locationProvider;

        public AndroidLocationService()
        {
            this.InitializeLocationManager();
        }

        //When the DI Container fetches a new instance of the AndroidLocationService
        //Wire up the _locationManager/Provider stuff and tell it to start fetching updates every 2 ses
        void InitializeLocationManager()
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine };
            try
            {
                _locationProvider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteriaForLocationService, true);
                if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(_locationProvider))
                {
                    _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 2000, 1, this);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        //MyInterface Method
        public LocationResult GetLocation()
        {

            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                return new LocationResult() { Data = "Can't determine the current address." };
            }

            return new LocationResult { Data = string.Format("{0} - {1}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude)};

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            _currentLocation = location;
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {
            //Not Implemented
        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {
            //Not Implemented
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
            //Not Implemented
        }
    }
}
```

`_locationProvider` gets set to the value `gps` by the `GetBestProvider` method, and it passes the `isEnabled` check, but as soon as it attempts to request updates... I get the following (rather unhelpful) Exception. I've double checked the app manifest to make sure the permissions are turned on for course & fine location requests. Any ideas ?

```
{Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException' was thrown.
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:508 
  at Android.Locations.LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (System.String provider, Int64 minTime, Single minDistance, ILocationListener listener) [0x0004a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.Locations.LocationManager.cs:814 
  at LoginDemo.Droid.AndroidLocationService.InitializeLocationManager () [0x00058] in c:\Work\Code\Sandbox\LoginDemo\LoginDemo\LoginDemo.Android\LocationService.cs:46 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null
    at android.location.LocationManager.checkListener(LocationManager.java:1606)
    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:426)
    at xamarin.forms.platform.android.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at xamarin.forms.platform.android.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:29)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 'normal' Android samples, the RequestLocationUpdates is called in OnResume. It looks to me that, by calling this method in the constructor (through the init method), you are trying to get this info too early. You could try to move the call to RequestLocationUpdates to a Start() method, that you can then call in the OnAppearing method of your page. I'm trying to get a sample working, but my mac needs some post-Yosemite-update work ;-)

UPDATE:

Ok, I think I figured it out. While my previous comment might still hold true, I found that instead of implementing Handle and Dispose in your ILocationListener implementation, you instead derive it from Java.Lang.Object. I found the answer from http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19559/xamarin-gps-location-code-fails-exception-in-mono-works-in-native-android-bug-or-mistake.

So in your code, remove the Dispose() and Handle code and change your class definition to :

```
public class AndroidLocationService : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationService, ILocationListener
```

I have made these changes in my little test app and it works as expected. Note that I did start the process in OnAppearing() (in the PCL) and that I use messaging (MessagingCenter) to update the label. In a full app, I would use MVVM and bind the label to the ViewModel, but even then, the ILocationService would probably still send its updates through MessagingCenter (you could use events as well, but in my experience, messaging is more reliable).

Comment: Thanks... will take that into account. The DI Service is instantiating this in the CTOR of a XAML page back in the PCL. I'll try move it into an OnResume, or other section of the app, or maybe fetch it during the button click and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the update... I did a quick test by extending java.lang.object, and init'ing the locMgr in OnAppearing of my app and it made the exceptions go away but the OnLocationChanged method never fires... will look into the message center stuff.

Comment: If you want, I can clean up my test project a little and put it on Github. Also, you can try using Xamarin Mobile which also has a GeoLocator class. Or dig into the MVVMCross code, which also has a Location plugin. It's not Xamarin Forms specific (although I think they are working on it), but it looks like your problem is Android specific anyway.

Comment: Yeah that'd be great man... if it's not too much hassle. really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Xamarin Forms Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator) this becomes much easier

```
        var geolocator = DependencyService.Get<IGeolocator> ();
```